# Where is HWPFDocument located? I can't find it in the POI project

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

Currently using:

```
<dependency><groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId><artifactId>poi</artifactId><version>3.10-FINAL</version></dependency>
```

I'm trying to write a simple program to get the word count of doc/x files. But some reason it is not able to find that specific method. Is it in another package or something? I've been googling and they are all pointing me to that pom.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As detailed on the [Apache POI Components and Dependencies page](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components), for HWPF you also need to include a Maven dependency on the `poi-scratchpad` artifact.

Your dependency in your pom will need to be something like:

```
<properties>
  <poi.version>3.11-beta2</poi.version>
 </properties>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>${poi.version}</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

(Non maven users need to add the `poi-scratchpad` jar from the binary package to their classpath, along with the `poi` jar you add now)